# Illegal assignment from List<AggregateResult> to List<Opportunity>

Tags: apex, soql

[image]public void stageN(string StgName)
{
list Stagelst= [SELECT Name,Count(StageName)
FROM Opportunity
where StageName=:StgName
Group by Name];
}

Hi Please help me with this
Error :-
Illegal assignment from List to List

Comment: The error is pretty clear. What have you tried to resolve this error? What part don't you understand?  Please edit your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the below code

List< AggregateResult > results = [SELECT Name, Count(StageName) FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName = :StgName GROPU BY Name];

Then you can iterate the result as below
for(AggregateResult result :results) {
String oppName = result.Name;
Integer stageCount = (Integer)result.get('exp0');

}

documentation for Aggregate SOQL https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm